# how to set the facebook style number notification?

Tags: javascript, notifications

I have a function named getnotification which is a json Ajax call.what i need is that the value returning from this Ajax call is "data.approvalSizelist".This contains a value for the notification value,lets say "95" ,i want this value to be displayed as a notification number like we see in facebook,how can i do this?

```
     function getNotificationNumber(){
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "retrieveApprovalNotificationNumber.action",
                data: null,
                success: function(data) {

                   alert(data.approvalSizelist);
                       },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            }
```

Approvals

I want to display the value in the top of  approvals,how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a div tag somewhere in your HTML identified with a unique id.

```
<div id="approval-size-list"></div>
```

If you are using jquery you can grab that element with the ID selector.
It will look like that

```
$("#approval-size-list")
```

The # mark is dedicated to selection by ID.

You can then call the .html() method on the above selected element.
The .html() method takes a single parameter that is the content you want to  display.

```
$("#approval-size-list").html(data.approvalSizelist);
```

Comment: i would also like to know,how we can hide notification after the click on  the corresponding notification.

Answer (score 1):

in Success function you can do like this

```
$('#divelementid').html(data.approvalSizelist);--assigns data
$("#divelementid").show();--show
$('#divelementid').delay(4000).hide();--hide element after some time
```

Comment: it works fine,but this will do a hide function after the specified time,what i need is on click of the notification,the notification should automatically go off.

Comment: @Coder - than you should attach click event on the div and stop current execution